# Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) is readonly

Tags: android, memory, readonly, internal

I try to recive from android the public music directory by:

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);

At my android 4.2 device it's /storage/emulated/0/Music and works well.

At android 5.0.1 device it's /storage/sdcard0/Music and readonly.

Why? I know that at 4.4 was restricted to write to the internal memory but it is public director, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that device sequrity politic is prevent access to Music directory to non system signed applications by emulated/0/Music (emulated file system). Can access to it by /data/0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but on developer.android.com it is stated:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

> Beginning with Android 4.4, these permissions are not required if you're reading or writing only files that are private to your app.

It is possible that not private location (to your app) still needs this permission?

By the way despite of this statment, I had to add this permission to work well in my app on Android 5.0.1.

Comment: I have this permission at the manifest. Yes I try to write out of my app private directory,  but I cant understand why Music is read only. It must be open for all.